# Dropping duplicate values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a frame like;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'America':["24,23,24,24","10","AA,AA, XY"]})
```

tried to convert it to a list, set etc.. but coudnt handle

how can i drop the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with `split` and `set`:

```
df['America'] = df['America'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(',')))
```

Another solution is use list comprehension:

```
df['America'] = [set(x.split(',')) for x in df['America']]
```

---

```
print (df)
     America
0   {23, 24}
1       {10}
2  {AA,  XY}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `str.split`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'America':["24,23,24,24","10","AA,AA, XY"]})
print(df["America"].str.split(",").apply(set))
```

**Output:**

```
0     {24, 23}
1         {10}
2    {AA,  XY}
Name: America, dtype: object
```